# `rails generate minitest:install` not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading an old Rails app to use MiniTest.
`rails generate minitest:install`

results in..

```
warning No license field                                                                                                                                 
Usage:
  rails generate minitest:install APP_PATH [options]
```

How do I get this to generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the new Webpacker included since Rails 5 and the suggested solution is to run `yarn install`, also another user stated that `NODE_ENV` was missing. You need to install yarn and fix the node issues first, then the issue will disappear.

See here, https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1374